# MySql query to get non sold products from inventory table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my project. One is 'Products' another is 'Inventory Movement'.

'Products' table is just a master table with all our products loaded. It has only 2 fields 
 id - Auto increment field for product id
 product_name - VarChar 255 unique column for product name

`'Inventory Movement'` table looks like below

```
id - Auto increment field

movement_type - Enum field (IN, OUT)

product - id from product table

quantity - No of items moving

movement_time - timestamp of action
```

Sample Data of `movement` table...

```
id     movement_type   product   Quantity  movement_time

1      IN              1001      10        2018-02-01 12:35:33

2      IN              1002      15        2018-02-01 13:33:33

3      OUT             1001      5         2018-03-01 11:00:33
```

now i have to take a report which list all products with the difference in time between its last 'OUT' and last 'IN' type records.

for a single product i wrote query like this...

1) Getting the last 'OUT' record;

```
 select movement_time from inventory_movement where product = '1001' and movement_type='OUT' order by movement_time desc limit 1
```

2) Getting the last 'IN' record;

```
 select movement_time from inventory_movement where product = '1001' and movement_type='IN' order by movement_time desc limit 1
```

3) Finding the diff between 2 timestamps.

this is how i know the unsold duration of the product with its id.

i know this is ineffective way... is there any way i can do this in single query ?

Is there anyway i get the list of products with this timestamp difference along with that ?

i.e.. the following is the expected output...

```
Product     ----     Time Difference between last Out and last In


1001      ----        40 days

1002      ----        45 days

1004      ----        12 days
```

Is it possible with single query ?

Comment: Is the query resolved ?

Comment: yes... it is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that a DATEDIFF between a conditional MIN and MAX should do.

```
SELECT product,
DATEDIFF(MAX(case when movement_type='OUT' then movement_time end), MIN(case when movement_type='IN' then movement_time end)) AS InOutDayDiff
from inventory_movement 
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY product
```

You can test it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f595d89/1/0)

Comment: thank you lukstorms that worked with a small change... where as both has to be MAX for me to take last inventory in aginst last inventory out. But the query you gave was nearly a nightmare for me to understand but it does the job perfect.

Comment: Thx. But to be honest, I'm a bit puzzled about how this would get the non-sold. But then again you'll understand your data best.